# Access static variable from a different class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, static-variables

So I have two classes:

A `Main` class with the `public static void main(String args[])` method
and a `Voice` class that accesses a static variable from that class.

Within the main class are methods that are used by itself, and are required to be static along with some of its variables.

So I have a static variable within the `Main` class (that's created/filled in the `public static void main(String args[])` method. That's why this case is special) which the other class should be able to access.

Here is an example of what's happening:

```
public class Main(){

    public static int variable;

    /*
        Unrelated methods go here.
    */
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Voice v = new Voice();//This is just here for the code to make sense.
        variable = 5;

        v.doSomething();

    }
}

public class Voice(){

    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println(Main.variable);
    }

}
```

Upon calling the `doSomething()` method in `Voice`, it leads to a `nullPointerException`.

I could fix this by passing on the `variable` variable to the `Voice` class, but is there a more easy way to fix this in the long run, if for instance, I needed to use more than one static variable from the `Main` class?

Comment: Don't use static variables.

Comment: Does the above code crash?  I don't see how it would?

Comment: Show your stacktrace please and indicate the exact line that causes it.

Comment: It seems you re using wrong Main class when you do Main.variable

Comment: Also you're posting non-compilable code. Please don't do this, don't post kind-of sort-of code, but instead show us real compilable and runnable code.

Comment: shouldn't it be `public static Voice {` without parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is having syntax error. You can use this

```
class Main{

    public static int variable;

    /*
        Unrelated methods go here.
    */
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Voice v = new Voice();//This is just here for the code to make sense.
        variable = 5;

        v.doSomething();

    }
}

class Voice{

    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println(Main.variable);
    }

}
```

Output will be 5

Answer (score -1):

You should do as follows

```
public class Main{

    public static int variable;

    /*
        Unrelated methods go here.
    */
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Voice v = new Voice();//This is just here for the code to make sense.
        variable = 5;

        v.doSomething();

    }
}

 class Voice{

    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println(Main.variable);
    }

}
```